# Broken img link but file exists in correct location

Tags: html, broken-image

I have two domains that link to the same site folder, one image loads but the main image link is broken. The files for both images are in exactly the same folder and the img src is a relative link, so it should work.

The site domains are:-

[www.exppublishing.com](http://www.exppublishing.com) [www.exppublishing.co.uk](http://www.exppublishing.co.uk)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: can you share your directory structure of the hosted application

Comment: File names in web servers are generally case-sensitive, are you making sure the file name is exactly that?

Comment: your image is not existing under Images folder, please check it once

Comment: Seems like it's just been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed...

I had previously hosted this site on a Windows shared server which worked fine, since moving it to a Linux shared server the link broke as the case of the filename didn't resolve correctly. I have since aligned the case to match the img src and it now works correctly.

Thanks for the suggestions.